# Does this use of Guave EventBus can be a performance hit?

Tags: google-app-engine, event-handling, guava

I just found out about google's event bus (after 1 day of googling "event queue java" "event bus java" and finding only stuff about GUIs).

It seems cool but my problem is : if we want eventbus to be a singleton we have to make all or observers singleton, and that is not possible since I also have a reference to my DataStore in this handlers.

So I choosed to create an eventbus per http request, so I have to register all my handlers for every http request (if my controller choose which event handler to register that would be breaking the whole pattern).

Do you think it might be a problem ? Or registering handlers is really fast and I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Do note that GAE is a distributed system (= multi JVM instances running in parallel) and Guava Eventbus is within-JVM.

Comment: I don't understand why I have to note it.

Comment: Do not think that it is a good architecture. Registration is fast, but it will add additional time to instance start time when you do not have instances enough. So you will decrease latency which is not good at all. GAE HTTP processing is not a good place for complex design patterns. You need to keep in mind that any HTTP request could start new instance and response time will be: instance start time + request env setup + request processing.

Comment: In my question I'm saying that I'll register my event handlers for every HTTP request , so I don't see where this could harm the instance start time. The problem is the same if ou have 1 instance or n, my code is not per instance start but per request start.